# How do you add more error codes for user login on YII?

Tags: yii

In yii I can use:

```
self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
```

I want another one:

```
self::ERROR_USER_BANNED;
```

That must give the error:

```
Sorry, but you cannot login because you account has been blocked.
```

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add it directly to your *protected/components/UserIdentity.php* :

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {
    const ERROR_USER_BANNED = -1; // say -1 you have to give some int value

    public function authenticate() {
        // ... code ...
        if (/* condition to check for banning */) { // you might want to put this check right after any other username checks, and before password checks
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USER_BANNED;
            $this->errorMessage='Sorry, but you cannot login because your account has been blocked.'
            return $this->errorCode;
        }
    }
}
```

The default way with *LoginForm.php* model :

Add a new validator rule, say to your `username` field:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        // ... other rules ...
        array('username','isBanned')
    );
}

// the isbanned validator
public function isBanned($attribute,$params) {
    if($this->_identity===null)
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);

    if($this->_identity->authenticate() === UserIdentity::ERROR_USER_BANNED){
        $this->addError($attribute,$this->_identity->errorMessage);
}
```

Ofcourse you could have declared another function in UserIdentity to check just for banning, and call that function from the `isBanned` validator, instead of having things in the `authenticate` function.

Comment: that'll depend on how you are logging in the user, the default way sets the errors in the LoginForm.php model file, are you using that?

Comment: I am yes. But not sure where it exactly says something like: "If (ERROR_USER_BANNED) $message = 'Bla bla bla'... that's the part I can't seem to match up.

Comment: Thanks bool.dev! You are definitely the YII guy on StackOverflow! :-)

Comment: grateful you think that, but there are many other great answerers, so i'm not THE guy. anyway, updated answer. edit: read the entire answer again, not just the added part, changed the previous code posted also a little

Answer (score 0):

add following in UserIdentity.php

```
const ERROR_USER_BANNED = 12 ; #or whateve int value you prefer


public function getErrorMessageX() #or whatever method name
{
    switch ($this->errorCode)
    {
        case self::ERROR_USER_BANNED:
            return 'sorry, your account has been banned'; # custom error msg

        case self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
            return 'User does not exists';

        case self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID:
            return 'Password does not match';

        case self::ERROR_ACCOUNT_NOT_CONFIRMED:           #this one is mine:)
            return 'This Account needs confirmation';
    }
}
```

now in LoginForm.php

```
public function authenticate( )
{
    $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);

    if( $this->_identity->authenticate() === FALSE )
        $this->addError('username', $this->_identity->errorMessageX); #here

            #some more code

    return !$this->_identity->errorCode;
}
```

Comment: Side-Not: remember to rename the property according to method